# Será que esta é uma "pergunta camaleão"?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Vi a pergunta [**Eclipse - NullPointerException**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9918/201) na análise de votos para reabrir. Ele foi fechada como "não clara sobre o que está perguntando" pois o usuário tinha postado centenas de linhas de código basicamente pedindo "debuguem meu projeto completo".

Ainda assim, recebeu uma resposta que segundo um comentário do OP:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso tem toda pinta de [**Pergunta Camaleão**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) (que vai mutando de um problema a outro) e, se for o caso, creio que basicamente invalida a [resposta do Paulo Roberto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9921/201).

Enfim, não tenho certeza por que não conheço Java, mas desconfio do que está acontecendo quanto à reabertura dessa pergunta.

Comment: Bom você ter chamado a atenção para o fato, eu estava quase votando pra reabrir também... Me parece ser o caso, sim, veja [essa outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10324/problema-com-cursor) - aparentemente o OP abriu ela após a primeira ser fechada. Os códigos parecem ser o mesmo, mas o problema é diferente. Talvez seja só o caso de orientá-lo para continuar fazendo isso: abrindo perguntas novas para problemas novos (desde que on topic, é claro), em vez de mudar a pergunta original como foi feito na primeira.

Comment: Talvez fosse o caso de fazer um *rollback* pra versão 1 da pergunta...

Comment: Concordo. A atitude melhor seria fazer rollback para versão 1, e deixar minha resposta ali para uso dos usuários quem quer que precise resolver um problema deste tipo saberá a resposta, e logo após, abrir uma outra pergunta para o novo erro.

Comment: @mgibsonbr a que vc linkou parece uma duplicata [dessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10099/3117), mas não tenho certeza pq não to com tempo pra ficar analisando

Comment: @Math De fato, parece que o OP mexeu um pouquinho no código, mas a causa raiz de ambas as perguntas é a mesma. Votei pra fechar.

Comment: Se minha pergunta tiver gerado algum tipo de transtorno, peço que me avisem, para que eu não cometa o erro de novo. Estou evitando postar mais perguntas "desnecessárias" no SO-BR. Peço desculpas, de qualquer forma.

Comment: Não fiquei a perceber se é melhor abrir uma nova pergunta, no caso de outro problema distinto com o mesmo código, se editar a pergunta e colocar as novas dúvidas?

Comment: Mais um exemplo de uma pergunta camaleão, mas sem respostas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23249/7210
@bfavaretto o que fazer nestas situações? Sinalizar? Votar para fechar? Ou deixar aberta se e só se não houver respostas?

Comment: Uma pergunta camaleão invalida as resposta já dadas, o que não é o caso ali, @JorgeB. Mas os comentários ficaram obsoletos e teriam que ser removidos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu votei contra reabrir por causa disto: a pergunta tinha sido alterada, e a resposta que já tinha ajudado ficaria inválida etc.

Não vi também que tinha aberto uma nova pergunta, tanto que na primeira pergunta eu coloquei 2 comentários gigantes sobre o que estava levando o pessoal a votar negativo e a pedir para fechar a pergunta.

Posso copiar depois os comentários de lá como resposta aqui, se for o caso.