# O que fazer quando o O.P muda sua pergunta?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Nesta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23823/), o *Original Poster* <sup><sub>(Autor da Pergunta)</sub></sup> questionou sobre o uso de `time.sleep` nas condições de controle (if, else). E depois quando viu a minha resposta para sua pergunta, viu que precisava de alguma coisa diferente e alterou a sua pergunta tornando a minha resposta ínválida' para o que a pergunta diz no momento.

Um outro usuário criticou-me por não ter tentado responder a pergunta pois quando ele viu a pergunta não era a que eu havia respondido [como pode ser visto nas revisões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/23823/revisions).

Eu quero saber qual deve ser nossa postura quando a isso, e não tenho certeza mais acho que a tag para esse post é [debate](/questions/tagged/debate) uma vez que não há um procedimento padrão.

Comment: Eu diria que seria interessante adicionar uma linha no topo da resposta dizendo que a resposta é para uma versão antiga da pergunta.

Comment: Relacionada: [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/229289)

Comment: Rollback. Sem perdão. Já fiz lá.

Comment: Sei que essa questão é 'velha' e o que vou falar é meio sem relação, mas não quero publicar uma nova pergunta para algo pequeno assim: Alguem me explica o que é O.P? '~'

Comment: @OlimonF. :Como definido [nesta resposta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40354)(em inglês). O.P. significa "Original Poster" isto é quem escreveu (neste caso a pergunta) mas também pode ser válido (em certos casos) para alguma resposta.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Essa situação é conhecida como **Pergunta Camaleão**. A pergunta camaleão se caracteriza por mudar completamente o problema exposto ***depois*** que foi fornecida uma resposta, deixando-a inválida.

Se a resposta (ou respostas) se referem a uma única versão da pergunta, o correto é fazer um Rollback para essa versão e avisar o *Original Poster* (autor da post) que ele/a deve publicar uma nova pergunta para resolver um novo problema. A pessoa gastou seu tempo e conhecimentos para fornecer uma resposta adequada a um problema, não é correto mudar a pergunta e invalidar esse esforço.
Se por acaso o OP fizer outro Rollback, não entre em guerra de edição, sinalize e avise os moderadores.

O problema se complica se uma resposta se refere a uma versão, e outra resposta se refere à nova versão da pergunta. Num caso desses, deve-se sinalizar para atenção dos moderadores e/ou abrir uma pergunta aqui no Meta para tentar resolver o caso.

Isso já ocorreu em uma pergunta que respondi no SOen e fiz o Rollback imediatamente avisando o OP de como se deve proceder. No caso aqui relatado, fiz a mesma coisa.

Referências:

- [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)
  Nesta e nas perguntas relacionadas pode-se confirmar que o que descrevo é o [comportamento](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43480/185667) que se considera [adequado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225647/185667) na rede.
- [Será que esta é uma “pergunta camaleão”?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1115/201)

Comment: +1 "e fiz o Rollback imediatamente avisando o OP de como se deve proceder"

Comment: Ora, pois sim, normalmente são usuários novatos que não conhecem o sistema de Pergunta & Resposta. Fazer o Rollback rapidamente evita: 1) comentários mal-informados e votos negativos na sua resposta. 2) que alguém responda à nova versão da pergunta tornando a situação uma meleca total. @JorgeB.

Comment: Concordo totalmente brasofilo por isso dei o +1. Acho deve ser feito logo, assim como fechar perguntas MUITO amplas. Mas isso já é outra discussão :)

Comment: +10 por "meleca total" ahahahahah

Comment: @Maria, me parece que é mais um "narrow focus" (não sei como dizer em português) do que uma completa reformulação. Se for isso, talvez seja o caso de fazer a mesma coisa com sua resposta (se for possível). Se não for possível, coloque um aviso no começo da sua resposta *"estou respondendo à primeira versão da pergunta [link pra revisão]"*. Se realmente é uma mudança completa, dê o toque *"por favor, confirme que sua pergunta não é uma pergunta camaleão [link pra este meta tópico]"*. Opção final, delete a resposta e procure outra pergunta mais interessante ;)