# Edição completas de perguntas

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica, comentários, perguntas-fechadas

Ontem dada a minha boa disposição decidi passar pelo SOpt(Site de perguntas e respostas) e procurar diligentemente responder questões que estivessem ao meu alcance. Apercebi-me de uma (que já não existe, e nem era uma questão) e fiz um comentário.

Volta e meia, após a mesma "questão ter sido negativada" o OP editou(foi mais uma substituição, pois mudou TUDO), colocando uma outra questão complementarmente diferente da "questão anterior". A minha questão é se deve de facto ser permitida a edição completa(substituição) de uma questão?

Por outra, eu seria obrigado a remover todo e qualquer comentário referente a questão anterior, senão eu é que fico mal na fita.

Eis o link onde observei este acontecimento (o meu comentário já foi removido):

[Como ordenar corretamente uma tag <ui:repeat> do JSF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34186/como-ordenar-corretamente-uma-tag-uirepeat-do-jsf)

Comment: @brasolfilo Obrigado pela correção na definição do SO (mudei de Fórum para Site de perguntas e respostas). :D

Comment: Quer provocar uma tempestade? Vai lá no [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) ou [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) e fala que o site é um fórum :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pergunta inicial era uma mensagem a ser postada em uma rede social qualquer: *"quero participar de comunidades..."*. O SOpt não é uma rede social nem um fórum, é um site de Perguntas e Respostas, vide [*O SOPT se encaixa na categoria de “rede social”?*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1361/201)

Depois da edição, a pergunta foi adequada ao site: *"tenho uma dúvida com este código..."* e está sendo votada para reabertura (eu tinha votado pelo fechamento e negativado, agora votei para reabrir e reverti o negativo).

Seu comentário ficou obsoleto e pode ser sinalizado para remoção:

> [image]

Comentários não são considerados permanentes e podem ser removidos uma vez cumpriram sua função. Quando você detectar isso é melhor você mesmo deletar. Mas, se sinalizados, os moderadores tem poder para removê-los. E, dependendo do tipo e quantidade de sinalizações, serão removidos automaticamente <sup>(não estou localizando uma meta pergunta relevante)</sup>.

Como não houve respostas à pergunta, não há problema em que ela tenha mutado de uma coisa para outra ("pergunta camaleão"), vide [*O que fazer quando o O.P muda sua pergunta?*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1682/201). Inclusive, é melhor não deletar perguntas quando se é novo no site pois isso é levado em conta no [Bloqueio de Perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).

Comment: Entendido. Agora e se houvesse uma resposta a questão, como se haveria de proceder?

Comment: Se houvesse resposta, isso teria constituído a tal Pergunta Camaleão. Se não tiver certeza como proceder, o melhor é abrir uma Meta pergunta para tratar do assunto.