# Uma nova dúvida surge após a pergunta ser respondida

Tags: suporte, perguntas

Por exemplo, eu faço uma pergunta, obtenho a resposta e resolvo meu problema. Porém na sequência surge uma outra dúvida relacionada ao mesmo assunto, mas diferente. Devo fazer uma nova pergunta ou editar a primeira? Qual seria a solução correta?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O mais apropriado é você criar uma nova pergunta, se houver a necessidade você pode colocar um link para sua pergunta antiga para dar contexto à ela.

O que você cogitou em fazer tornaria a sua pergunta uma [**Pergunta Camaleão**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1115/3117). Esse tipo de pergunta não é benéfica para a comunidade por alguns motivos:

- Ao mudar sua pergunta você invalida as respostas já existentes;
- As perguntas são o que movem o site, portanto, desejamos ter um alto número de perguntas (sem deixar a qualidade de lado);
- Muitas dúvidas diferentes na mesma pergunta a torna confusa atraindo respostas de baixa qualidade e deixando o site bagunçado.

O ideal realmente é separar suas dúvidas em várias perguntas.

Não existe um limite atingível de perguntas legítimas que podem ser feitas no site, portanto não precisa ficar economizando, vá em frente e crie uma nova.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, deixei de fazer umas perguntas por ter essa dúvida, mas agora que já sei irei fazer isso. Estou começando no ramo da programação e o site tem me ajudado muito! ;)

Comment: É muito bom saber que o site o tem ajudado @GWER :)

Comment: Acho que existe sim um limite de perguntas, não sei se por dia, por mês ou ambos.

Comment: @bfvararetto obviamente só para evitar exagero em *farmming* e principalmente em *minning*. Duvido que alguém estoure o limite de forma legítima.

Comment: @bfavaretto Parece que são [50!?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272833/352449) por mês. Mas todos os limites podes ser observados em detalhe [aqui](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/184576).

Comment: @bfavaretto se existe um limite para fazer perguntas vamos descobrir isso hoje com o [Paulo Costa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15077/paulo-costa)

Comment: @Math Acho que ainda é pouco :s

Comment: @bfavaretto ele apagou várias e encerrou sua maratona de perguntas depois de uma conversa iniciada pelo mgibsonbr nessa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61456/3117