# Pergunta camaleão com recompensa

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, recompensa

A pergunta ["Input radio que parece checkbox?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57068/215) já havia sido respondida de forma adequada (no meu entender), mas ao aplicar a solução surgiu uma nova dúvida (["pergunta camaleão"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1115/215)). A AP optou por oferecer uma recompensa na própria pergunta, em vez de fazer uma nova - o que é razoável, pois do ponto de vista dela havia uma falha na solução proposta. O problema é que na realidade a resposta dada não tinha essa falha, ela surgiu quando a AP tentou adaptá-la ao seu caso particular.

Pra complicar mais a situação, um usuário que não tinha reputação suficiente para comentar postou uma resposta, que responde especificamente à dúvida levantada na recompensa, mas não é uma resposta [distinta] à pergunta original. O próprio usuário deixou uma nota esclarecendo isso, dando liberdade à comunidade para remover a resposta se achar necessário.

O que fazer, se é que precisa fazer alguma coisa? Converter a resposta em comentário e desfazer a recompensa? Manter a resposta, mas sugerir alguma coisa pra AP? (tipo, aceitar a primeira resposta, mas dar a recompensa pra segunda) Não interferir, deixar que a AP decida sozinha o que prefere fazer?

Cabe notar - e isso talvez seja assunto para uma nova pergunta, mais genérica - que o tipo de recompensa escolhido:

> As respostas estão desatualizadas e precisam ser revisadas, devido às recentes alterações.

é praticamente um **convite** a perguntas camaleão! Da forma como foi traduzida, ela foge um pouco do "espírito" da recompensa, que é atualizar respostas antigas dadas mudanças no **cenário** (ex.: evolução da tecnologia), e não qualquer mudança que o autor da pergunta decida fazer na mesma. A propósito, a mensagem em inglês também não é das melhores:

> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

mas *"recent changes"* é ao menos uma expressão mais genérica, que não especifica a natureza dos *changes* (algo mudou) - enquanto "alteração" é uma palavra bem mais específica (algo *foi mudado*).

Comment: E *out-of-date* também ajuda a clarificar... A tradução está um bocado (grande) má...

Comment: E está ai uma bela duma confusão! @mgibsonbr ótimo para uma sexta feita :D

Comment: @JorgeB. haha e o pior é que mal eu acabei de abrir esse debate e [me surgiu um problema de última hora](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57854/215) que não vai me permitir dar atenção a esse assunto... :P

Comment: Acho que não tiveste sorte com nenhuma das duas, ninguém te responde...

Comment: @JorgeB. Nessas alturas, melhor deixar tudo como está mesmo (a primeira resposta, correta, foi aceita e levou a recompensa, e a segunda continua lá, mas não está fazendo mal a ninguém...). Quanto à outra lá, se aparecer alguém com uma solução boa, ótimo, senão vou de gambiarra mesmo, fazer o que...

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eu não achei que ela fosse atribuir a recompensa antes do fim do prazo. Claramente tem algumas coisas que ela não entendeu sobre o site... Eu estava vendo com o Gabe se tinha como migrar a outra resposta para uma possível nova pergunta (mas não existe ferramenta para isso), e fui pego de surpresa pelo encerramento prematuro da recompensa. Tem razão, nesta altura é melhor deixar como está. Mas vou deixar  algumas orientações para a AP lá na pergunta.

Comment: Opa, olha eu aqui bagunçando tudo! Acabei de saber da confusão rs
Eu não mudei a pergunta, só achei que não tinha sido clara o suficiente, e acho que usei alguns termos técnicos de forma incorreta..

Comment: E sobre a recompensa, eu achava que era um recurso que eu poderia usar para conseguir melhores respostas em curto prazo!

Comment: @HendyAlmeida Sim, de fato, como expliquei sua atitude foi correta pois *do seu ponto de vista* a resposta era falha (ainda que na realidade não fosse). A "confusão" começou quando o segundo usuário - que não podia comentar - respondeu e foi bem votado. E a crítica no final foi **ao sistema**, e não a ninguém em particular - pois a descrição na tela de recompensas de fato sugere que mudar a pergunta é ok (você pode não ter feito isso, mas muitos outros usuários fazem, e não é bom "encorajá-los" rsrs).